# Is there a way to set the image source from a webcontrol's text in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I don't have any code or anything, I'm just wondering if I can set the image source dynamically, because I need the text parameter from a webcontrol label in order to set the image source.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why'd i get a downvote? can't one ask?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the specific question you asked is, yes you can.  If you want code to do so, show us what you have tried and we can help from there.